# Add network credentials in Ruby

Tags: ruby, http, azure-devops, credentials

I have a question about how the network credentials can be added to a request in Ruby?

I have tried to make a request but it was rejected because it does not have credentials. At the moment I have something like that:

```rb
url = URI.parse("http://dev.azure/tfs/#{collection}/#{proyect}/_apis/git/repositories/#{idrepositori}/pullrequest/#{idPR}?api-version=5.0")
puts "  url #{url}"
req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(url, 'Content-Type' => 'application/json') 
res = Net::HTTP.start(url.hostname, url.port) do |http| 
  http.request(req) 
end
```

Comment: How are the credentials supposed to be submitted?

Comment: That's my question, I'm new to ruby

Comment: No, I mean protocol-wise :-) How does the web service expect the credentials? Are you supposed to add a HTTP header?

Comment: With username and password, it is a request to an azure devops server 2019 api

Comment: I have tried with postman, and it works fine with NTLM Authentication

Comment: There are many ways to submit a username and password. For example - does the server support basic auth? A common method is to provide username and password encoded in basic auth headers. See https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.6.0/Net/HTTP.html#class-Net::HTTP-label-Basic+Authentication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, using a ntlm / http library

This must also be exported in the gem file

```
ruby "2.6.6"
source "https://rubygems.org"
gem "dependabot-omnibus", "~> 0.118.8"
gem 'ruby-ntlm', '~> 0.0.4'
```

The ruby code can be worked with the ntlm_auth function

```
require 'uri'
require 'net/http'
require 'json'
require 'ntlm/http'
    
url = URI.parse("http://dev.azure/tfs/#{collection}/#{proyect}/_apis/git/repositories/#{idrepositori}/pullrequest/#{idPR}?api-version=5.0")
    puts "  url #{url}"
    req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(url, 'Content-Type' => 'application/json') 
    req.ntlm_auth('User','Domain', 'Password')
    req.body = {"status": "completed","lastMergeSourceCommit": {"commitId": "123"},"completionOptions":{"deleteSourceBranch":"true"}}.to_json                
    res = Net::HTTP.start(url.hostname, url.port) do |http| 
      http.request(req) 
    end
```